# How to Center Button in Bootstrap 3.0.2

Tags: button, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get a button centered on a page. I've tried probably over 50 ways and nothing has worked.
Here's my code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 25px; align:center;">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <p style="text-align:center; margin-bottom: 25px; font-size: 135%;">Sample text.</p>
      <p style="text-align:center; padding-left: 40%; padding-right:40%;"><div class="button"><a href="www.exampleURL.com" target="_blank"><strong>Donate</strong></a></div> </p>      
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas? I've tried adding text-center, align:center--almost every variation you could think of--to every different tag and nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways is to make use of class `text-center` on `<div>` in which `<button>` is wrapped , Below is the working code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class=row>
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center"> 
      <button id="centerbutton" name="centerbutton" class="btn btn-primary"> Button in Center</button> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the Working [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Panther_007/kdok0a1b/3/) in [Bootstrap 3.0.2](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.0.2/docs/getting-started/)

Comment: Thanks, but that still didn't work. Does it have something to do with the fact that I'm not using the <button> element, but instead am using class="button"? Sorry if that's a stupid question...I'm new to Bootstrap.

Comment: you can use `<div class = "btn">` not `button` as `btn` is built in bootstrap class for buttons

Answer (score 0):

As button is an inline element, you can use the class center-block to center the button (or any inline element) in the containing div without the need for a text-center class.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class=row>
    <div class="col-md-4"> 
      <button id="centerbutton" name="centerbutton" class="btn btn-primary center-block"> Button in Center</button> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```